# plyr package writing the same function over multiple columns

Tags: r, plyr

I want to write the same function to multiple columns using ddply function, but I'm tried keep writing them in one line, want to see is there better way of doing this?

Here's a simple version of the data:

```
data<-data.frame(TYPE=as.integer(runif(20,1,3)),A_MEAN_WEIGHT=runif(20,1,100),B_MEAN_WEIGHT=runif(20,1,10))
```

and I want to find out the sum of columns A_MEAN_WEIGHT and B_MEAN_WEIGHT by doing this:

```
ddply(data,.(TYPE),summarise,MEAN_A=sum(A_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_B=sum(B_MEAN_WEIGHT))
```

but in my current data I have more than 8 "*_MEAN_WEIGHT", and I'm tired of writing them 8 times like

```
ddply(data,.(TYPE),summarise,MEAN_A=sum(A_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_B=sum(B_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_C=sum(C_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_D=sum(D_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_E=sum(E_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_F=sum(F_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_G=sum(G_MEAN_WEIGHT),MEAN_H=sum(H_MEAN_WEIGHT))
```

Is there a better way to write this? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `plyr`-centred approach is to use `colwise`

eg

```
 ddply(data, .(TYPE), colwise(sum))
  TYPE A_MEAN_WEIGHT B_MEAN_WEIGHT
1    1      319.8977      60.80317
2    2      621.6745      37.05863
```

You can pass the column names as the argument `.col`  if you want only a subset

You can also use `numcolwise` or `catcolwise` to act on numeric or categorical columns only.

note that you could use `sapply` in place of the most basic use of `colwise`

```
ddply(data, .(TYPE), sapply, FUN = 'mean')
```

---

The idiomatic data.table approach is to use `lapply(.SD, fun)`

eg

```
dt <- data.table(data)
dt[,lapply(.SD, sum) ,by = TYPE]
   TYPE A_MEAN_WEIGHT B_MEAN_WEIGHT
1:    2      621.6745      37.05863
2:    1      319.8977      60.80317
```

Comment: Thanks @mnel! just a one more question, it doesn't seem I can write it this way ddply(data, .(TYPE),colwise(sum,.(A_MEAN_WEIGHT)),colwise(sqrt,.(B_MEAN_WEIGHT))), so if I want two different functions over multiple columns, I need to write them twice?

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
ddply(data, .(TYPE), colSums)
```

Here's a (slower) equivalent of the above, that can be tweaked to put any function instead of summing:

```
ddply(data, .(TYPE), function(x) {apply(x, 2, sum)})
```

And if you want to preserve the `.(TYPE)` column, smth like this will do:

```
ddply(data, .(TYPE), function(x) {apply(x[,names(x) != "TYPE"], 2, sum)})
```

Better yet, use `data.table` instead of `plyr`:

```
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(data)

# just sums
dt[, data.table(t(colSums(.SD))), by = TYPE]

# sum for "A" and "B", and sqrt(sum) for "C" and "D"
# note: you will have to call setnames() to fix the column names after
dt[, data.table(t(colSums(.SD[, c("A_MEAN_WEIGHT", "B_MEAN_WEIGHT"), with = F])),
                t(apply(.SD[, c("C_MEAN_WEIGHT", "D_MEAN_WEIGHT"), with = F],
                        2, function(x) sqrt(sum(x))))),
     by = TYPE]
```

Comment: Emm...follow up question, what if I have 16 columns, and I want to do sum for 8 of them, and sqrt(sum) of the other 8....

Comment: You could e.g. run the above command twice - once with each function and filtering by columns you want (e.g. by doing `names(x) %in% c("column_a", "column_b", ...)` in `apply` or by column number or whatever is appropriate for your data) and then `cbind` the result

Comment: You can alternatively run the `dt[, ...]` business twice using different values for `.SDcols` each time then `cbind` the result, if you catch my meaning ...

Comment: Don't use `colSums` on a `data.table` or `apply` -- both will convert to a matrix internally, and therefore are not  efficient.

Comment: Don't use colSums or apply on a data.frame either.

Comment: @mnel in my tests `dt[, colSums(.SD)]` is about 10% faster than `dt[, lapply(.SD, sum)]`, so I don't think your comment is correct

Comment: It may not bite when you are dealing with small data sets. But look at the source code for each function, and do some benchmarking with large data.

Comment: fair enough, running more checks, indeed `colSums` is faster on smaller data, but becomes slower with larger data